# How to adapt my app to tablet without fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've developed an application designed for 4 inches devices (min SDK 8 - Android 2.3.3).
Now I need to support also tablets (7 inches or 10 inches).
The app (as it is) on tablets covers a bit more than half screen.
This is not acceptable for users.

I would like to move all objects (TextView, Buttons, ImageView) in order to occupy the whole screen.

Because the min SDK is 8 (Android 2.3.3) I cannot use Fragment, I'm right?

I've tried using screen percentage without substantial results (I'm a newbie!!!).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: of-course you can use fragment. Use supporting jar provided by android and fragments will work with lower version as well

Comment: How can I do? Where can I find that jar and how can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your app to run on tablets too. you have to make layouts for Tablet in a separate folder under res e.g.

```
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
```

also use hdpi/x-hdpi images in drawable as well

see guidelines given by android

### http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

and also here

### http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: This was the right way, but I'found that now it's deprecated and it's suggested to use layout-sw600dp and layout-sw720dp instead of layout-large and layout-xlarge.